# use of extend ActiveSupport::Concern

Tags: ruby, activesupport

I'm working through CodeSchool's RubyBits and I've come to an exercise I'm just not comprehending: "**Make sure the AtariLibrary class includes only the LibraryUtils module and let ActiveSupport::Concern take care of loading its dependencies. Then, refactor the self.included method on LibraryUtils to use the included method**."

```
module LibraryLoader

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def load_game_list
    end
  end
end

module LibraryUtils
  def self.included(base)
    base.load_game_list
  end
end

class AtariLibrary
  include LibraryLoader
  include LibraryUtils
end
```

Based on the solution (below) it seems like `ActiveSupport::Concern` doesn't take care of loading the dependencies - you need to include LibraryLoader inside of LibraryUtils.

Can you help me understand just what `ActiveSupport::Concern` is doing, and why it needs to be called via `extend` in both modules?

```
module LibraryLoader
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def load_game_list
    end
  end
end

module LibraryUtils
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include LibraryLoader

  #result of refactoring the self.included method
  included do
    load_game_list
  end
end

class AtariLibrary
  include LibraryUtils
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

When you call `extend ActiveSupport::Concern` it will look for a ClassMethods inner-module and will extend your 'host' class with that.  Then it will provide you with an `included` method which you can pass a block to:

```rb
included do
 some_function
end
```

The `included` method will be run within the context of the included class.  If you have a module that requires functions in another module, `ActiveSupport::Concern` will take care of the dependencies for you.